# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) when use RxJava and play services vision

Tags: android, rx-java, face-detection

In my application I use the definition of the person position in the picture. After that, using RxJava I process the resulting image and output the result. After complete re-run that process. All working perfectly on devices such as samsung, huawei, meizu and other (with android version 5.0 and higher). But on xiaomi (no matter what version of android) I getting this error:

> A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xabc932a8 passed
>   to dlfree A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr
>   0xdeadbaad in tid 28493 (RxNewThreadSche) A/DEBUG: pid: 28376, tid:
>   28493, name: RxNewThreadSche  >>> com.package.name <<<

Sometimes it crashes after start procces, sometimes it working 5-6 times. But it always force finishing my application. 
I can't put here all my code but I think this is due to:

```
FaceDetector.release();
```

because when I don't use this line my app crashed if not, just not working FaceDetector (on other devices i used it).

After crash xiaomi generated [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsfk5.png) error.

**EDIT**

```
private static FaceDetector sFaceDetector;
private static FaceDetectorUtil sFaceDetectorUtil;
private static WeakReference<Context> mContext;

public static void init(Context context) {
    if (sFaceDetectorUtil == null) {
        sFaceDetectorUtil = new FaceDetectorUtil(context);
    }
}

private FaceDetectorUtil(Context context) {
    mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
}

public static FaceDetector getDetector() {
    if (sFaceDetector != null) {
        sFaceDetector.release();
    }
    return sFaceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(mContext.get())
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .build();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Current threads in getFaceDetector method:

**Huawei P9 lite**: 
Count: 13
 Threads: HeapTaskDaemon
 Threads: FinalizerDaemon
 Threads: RxComputationThreadPool-2
 Threads: pool-1-thread-1
 Threads: GoogleApiHandler
 Threads: RxComputationThreadPool-1
 Threads: JavaCPP Deallocator
 Threads: ReferenceQueueDaemon
 Threads: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
 Threads: RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1
 Threads: RxComputationThreadPool-3
 Threads: RxNewThreadScheduler-17
 Threads: pool-2-thread-1

**Xiaomi Redmi 4x**:
Count: 22
Threads: Signal Catcher
Threads: RxComputationThreadPool-2
Threads: Binder:5858_3
Threads: Binder:5858_2
Threads: hwuiTask1
Threads: RxComputationThreadPool-1
Threads: JDWP
Threads: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
Threads: RenderThread
Threads: RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1
Threads: RxComputationThreadPool-3
Threads: ReferenceQueueDaemon
Threads: Binder:5858_1
Threads: pool-1-thread-1
Threads: JavaCPP Deallocator
Threads: HeapTaskDaemon
Threads: main
Threads: GoogleApiHandler
Threads: FinalizerDaemon
Threads: RxNewThreadScheduler-4
Threads: hwuiTask2
Threads: pool-2-thread-1

I would really appreciate if someone can help to me. Regards!

Comment: When are you calling `FaceDetector.release()`? Are there are other threads that are still using it?

Comment: @cwbowron nope, just one which pocces image

Answer (score 2):

The error is not caused by RxJava. It is caused by native code, probably by the library libmobile_vision_face.so.

If you can't change the native code you can workaround the error by avoid calling `FaceDetector.release()` and initialising it only once (in your `Application` class for example).

**UPD:** for the singleton approach I had in mind to use it as follows:

```
public static FaceDetector getDetector() {
    if (sFaceDetector != null) {
        return sFaceDetector;
    } else {
        return sFaceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(mContext.get())
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Also you could just try to add the synchronisation to your method first, in case if you try to call it in parallel (what could lead to the error):

```
public static synchronized FaceDetector getDetector() {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. For FaceDetector initializing I am using singletone class (updated my question) is this what you mean?

Comment: But it not on xiaomi(

Comment: Just updated the answer to make it clear, what I mean

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I was exactly used that a little earlier=) Not helping, but thanks

Comment: I was decided to check how many thread in getDetector method in Huawei and Xiaomi. Output in my question.