# Android app crashed without stack : how to debug?

Tags: android, google-vision

I am testing Google Mobile Vision library on my Samsung Note 8, from time to time, My app crashes with a `A/libc: Fatal signal 11`, but there is no stack trace at all, even when running with android studio debugger.
I got only :

```
...V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ed7d6d6 nm : info.lapouyade.dcinventory ic=null
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x793081d8c0
                  endAllActiveAnimators on 0x79291bcc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x791d701b60
D/ViewRootImpl@dc5d321[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
D/ViewRootImpl@10d3d9f[BarcodeToFieldActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=117KB, data=84KB
            After code cache collection, code=117KB, data=84KB
            Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=251KB, data=178KB
            After code cache collection, code=173KB, data=115KB
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=250KB, data=164KB
            After code cache collection, code=250KB, data=164KB
            Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 1705 (Thread-4)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

There is no exception, so I cannot catch anything : How to get a stack in such a crash ?

Comment: Do you have access to the libc Code?

Comment: Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) means there is a problem in native code. Do you use some native libraries?

Comment: You have the first line of a native crash there.  The rest should be right below it in logcat.

Comment: [Hey ! .. is this thread might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077045/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-when-use-rxjava-and-play-services-vision)

Comment: I used the logcat from android studio which seems to be much less verbose than the adb logcat. adb logcat was the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get the Whole `stack trace` by printing it to a `logcat.txt` file

You can use the command from `Android Studio` terminal

> Please make sure before using this that you have already set the `adb`
>   path to your System Variable to use it Globally.

```
adb logcat -> logcat.txt
```

After a crash occurs you can check this `logcat.txt` file to get the Exact Error.

last week, I am also facing the same Issue but this way I able to capture the whole scenario.
Hope this may help you

Comment: I have already checked the Logcat window from Android studio, but I found no stack. May be I missed something, I will try your way...

Comment: also, verify that you have enabled debugging for the NDK.